# How the OS knows when an I/O operation has finished execution?

Tags: io, operating-system

Consider the situation, where you issue a read from the disc (I/O operation). Then what is the exact mechanism that the OS uses to get to know whether the operation has been executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then what is the exact mechanism that the OS uses to get to know whether the operation has been executed?

The exact mechanism depends on the specific hardware (and OS and scenario); but typically when a device finishes doing something the device triggers an IRQ that causes the CPU to interrupt whatever it was doing and switch to a device driver's interrupt handler.

Sometimes/often device driver ends up maintaining a queue or buffer of pending commands; so that when its interrupt handler is executed (telling it that a previous command has completed) it takes the next pending command and tells the device to start it. Sometimes/often this also includes some kind of IO priority scheme, where driver can ask device to do more important work sooner (while less important work is postponed/remains pending).

A device driver is typically also tied to scheduler in some way - a normal thread in user-space might (directly or indirectly - e.g. via. file system) request that data be transferred and the scheduler will be told to not give that thread CPU time because it's blocked/waiting for something; and then later when the transfer is completed the device driver's interrupt handler tells the scheduler that the requesting thread can continue, causing it to be unblocked/able to be given CPU time by scheduler again.